# Is homomorphism density of partially labeled graph continuous with respect to cut metric

Tags: random-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

Let $F=(V, E)$ be a finite simple graph on $n$ vertices with two labelled vertices, say $x, y$.  Let $W:[0, 1]^2\to [-1, 1]$ be symmetric function. Lov'asz's book (Large Networks and Graph Limits) defines the homomorphism density for the partially labelled graphs as
$$t_{x, y}(F, W):=\int_{[0, 1]^{n-2}}\prod_{ij\in E}W(x_i, x_j) \prod d x_i.$$

We know that $\int dx\;dy t_{x, y}(F, W)=\varphi(F, W)$ that is homomorphism density of $F$ into $W$. On the space of graphons $\varphi(F, W)$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to so-called 'cut metric'. I am trying to prove that the homomorphism density for the partially labelled graphs is also continuous with respect to the cut metric. I am not able to.

Any reference or hint would be highly appreciated!